# Part of Blender UI Windows disappears

Tags: windows

l have been creating a scene for sometime now. All of a sudden, the part of blender that has the File, Render, Window ,Help  you know, the part of the blender interface that allows you to switch between blender render and cycles and stuff..
It just vanished and was replaced by a programming window. Now, all I see are codes instead....
Any help?
[image]

Comment: Just use the white cross on a dark background in the upper right of your image (partially hidden by the line you drawn)

Comment: ohhhhh.that worked perfectly. thanks bro.

Comment: reallly appreciate your help

Comment: Also a bunch of your objects have inverted normals, so watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

On the far right of the part of the screen you circled you will see a little plus sign. Click that and you will restore your view.

Somehow you pulled down the menu to hide it. The plus sign in the interface lets you know you have some of the interface in that view hidden.